# Exporting Highchart Live Data to Table

Tags: highcharts

I have created a chart - similar to [Highcharts - Live Data Example](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data). The chart is working fine. I want to build a table with the same data under the chart. I tried to add the following:

exporting: {
showTable: true
}

The table gets built but there is no data that gets inputted in the table. I have tried looking online but can't find any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `viewData` method to update data-table after each chart redraw.

```
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    height: 600,
    events: {
      render: function() {
        this.viewData();
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uLk3nfjz/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#viewData

Comment: Thank you @ppotaczek. I was stuck for many hours trying to figure this one out. I am going to add the viewData method to my code.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, the export tab (hamburger icon) on the highcharts has an option to "view data table", if you click that, it will update the table with new values at the time you click "view data table"

[View Data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teeXi.png)